# Android Google Maps draw a path between two points

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to draw a path between two points and calculate how much time it will take to move from A to B. I have thought that it is trivial task for Google Maps API.

Everything that I found is small snippet about `PolyUtil` in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) and nothing about how to use it.

What I did ?

Inside `MapsActivity` in `onMapReady` method I'm trying to create an encoded path:

```
List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
latLngList.add(new LatLng(56.952503, 24.083719));
latLngList.add(new LatLng(55.877526, 26.533898));

String encodedPath = PolyUtil.encode(latLngList);
```

But what is the next ? How to draw this path on map ? How to calculate car/walking distance between this points ?

Comment: @Saveen these questions - answers are from 2010-2013. Is it actual ?

Comment: pls look at this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4157

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1106 take a look

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Path is sequence of point . One of the solution is to make HTTP request to Google maps API specifying your two locations as parameters and get back JSON describing the points required to make the path between the two points. Require code to do that are listed below :

1. Get direction URL require to call Google Maps API

> ```
> private String  getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest) {
>    // Origin of route
>  String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;
>
>  // Destination of route
>  String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;        
>
>
>  // Sensor enabled
>  String sensor = "sensor=false";            
>
>  // Building the parameters to the web service
>  String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;
>
>  // Output format
>  String output = "json";
>
>  // Building the url to the web service
>  String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
>
>
>  return url;
>
> }
> ```

2. Do the URL call in background

   ```
   private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       String data = "";
       try {
           MapHttpConnection http = new MapHttpConnection();
           data = http.readUr(url[0]);


       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
           Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
       }
       return data;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       new ParserTask().execute(result);
   }

   }
   ```

> ```
>   public class MapHttpConnection {
>   public String readUr(String mapsApiDirectionsUrl) throws IOException{
>       String data = "";
>       InputStream istream = null;
>       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
>       try {
>           URL url = new URL(mapsApiDirectionsUrl);
>           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>           urlConnection.connect();
>           istream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
>           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
>           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
>           String line ="";
>           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>               sb.append(line);
>           }
>           data = sb.toString();
>           br.close();
>
>
>       }
>       catch (Exception e) {
>           Log.d("Exception while reading url", e.toString());
>       } finally {
>           istream.close();
>           urlConnection.disconnect();
>       }
>       return data;
>
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Create Parser class to parse the data from **JSON** to List of pointes

   ```
   public class PathJSONParser {

   public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {
       List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
       JSONArray jRoutes = null;
       JSONArray jLegs = null;
       JSONArray jSteps = null;
       try {
           jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
           for (int i=0 ; i < jRoutes.length() ; i ++) {
               jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
               List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
               for(int j = 0 ; j < jLegs.length() ; j++) {
                   jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                   for(int k = 0 ; k < jSteps.length() ; k ++) {
                       String polyline = "";
                       polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                       List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                       for(int l = 0 ; l < list.size() ; l ++){
                           HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                           hm.put("lat",
                                   Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                           hm.put("lng",
                                   Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                           path.add(hm);
                       }
                   }
                   routes.add(path);
               }

           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return routes;

   }

   private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
       List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
       int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
       int lat = 0, lng = 0;

       while (index < len) {
           int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lat += dlat;

           shift = 0;
           result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lng += dlng;

           LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                   (((double) lng / 1E5)));
           poly.add(p);
       }
       return poly;
   }}
   ```
4. Do the parse using another **Thread**  to expand performance

> ```
> private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, List<List<HashMap<String , String >>>> {
>   @Override
>   protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
>           String... jsonData) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       JSONObject jObject;
>       List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
>       try {
>           jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
>           PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
>           routes = parser.parse(jObject);
>
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return routes;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
>       ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
>       PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;
>
>       // traversing through routes
>       for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
>           points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
>           polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
>           List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);
>
>           for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
>               HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
>
>               double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
>               double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
>               LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
>
>               points.add(position);
>           }
>
>           polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
>           polyLineOptions.width(4);
>           polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
>       }
>
>       googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
>
>   }}
> ```

4. When you want to get the path of two point

> ```
>  String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(latlngOne, latlngTwo);                    
>     ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();       
>     // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
>     downloadTask.execute(url);
> ```

To calculate distance between points

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(latLongA.latitude, latLongB.longitude,
                         latLongB.latitude, latLongB.longitude,
                         results);
```

the results will be in meters

Comment: What is MapHttpConnection in ReadTask ?

Comment: It's another Class i uses to holding the connection , I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.